# Bower error when pushing to Heroku : bower ENOTDIR ENOTDIR, not a directory '/tmp/build_xxx/bower_components

Tags: git, heroku, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I've got problem when I try to push a ember-cli project on Heroku.
This is the log which is return to me.

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Ember CLI app detected
remote: -----> Exporting config vars to environment
remote: -----> Building environment: production
remote: -----> Requested node range:  0.12.7
remote: -----> Resolved node version: 0.12.7
remote: -----> Downloading and installing node
remote: -----> Using default npm version: 2.11.3
remote: -----> Downloading and installing nginx
remote: -----> Adding boot script
remote: -----> Copying configs
remote: -----> Creating node_modules cache directory
remote: -----> Creating bower_components cache directory
remote: -----> Installing bower which is required by other  dependencies
remote:        bower@1.6.2 node_modules/bower
remote: -----> Pruning cached dependencies not specified in package.json
remote: -----> Pruning cached bower dependencies not specified in   bower.json
remote:        bower ENOTDIR       ENOTDIR, not a directory '/tmp/build_7092e0e145a6f8787208ecf8b53c932a/bower_components'
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ember CLI app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to my-app
```

I've tried to purge the cache with the heroku-repo but still the same problem.

If I compile the project with ember build, there's no problem. Just the message:

```
bower invalid-meta  ember is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
```

The deployment worked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this same issue today. This seems to be caused by the latest bower version 1.6.2 -- forcing the version to 1.5.3 resolved the issue here.

See this fork: https://github.com/AltSchool/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli/pull/1/files

EDIT: this has been merged into tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli: https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli/pull/110

Comment: OK. it works now. Just need to repush to heroku with `git push heroku master`. Thanks.